# Jenkins Pipeline Plugin execute external Step

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I'm developing a Jenkins plugin to use it in pipeline scripts.
The class extends Builder and implements SimpleBuildStep, annotated with @Extension.
There's a inner class which extends BuildStepDescriptor with @Extension and @Symbol.

Everywhing works fine, I'm able to use it from scripted pipeline, but I can't find a way to call external steps (other plugins) like for example *archiveArtifacts* or *readMavenPom* from Pipeline Utility Steps.

Is there a way to call them from my plugin?
I've searched docs with no luck.

Comment: You would need to import the packages representing those plugins. The plugins also need to be installed first.

Comment: I guess you mean by adding them as a maven dependency on my plugin's project and call their Java methods directly. I'll take a look at that.